# Does a bash fork bomb live forever?

Tags: linux, bash, security, ubuntu-14.04

According to Wikipedia's lemma about a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), especially if *Bash* is used, I want to know what happens if I would execute this code in my *Bash* and immediately, (or after some seconds), power off the machine.

1. Would the fork bomb be still alive if I restart the machine?
2. Or would this fork bomb have seriously damaged something?
3. Or is this kind of fork bomb just an academic issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relation to the `bash` fork bomb

```
#!/bin/bash
$0|$0& #"$0" returns the name of the shell script itself
```

Would the fork bomb be still alive if I restart the machine? No

Or would have this fork bomb something seriously damaged? No, it's meant to overload your system, which it does pretty quickly.

Or is this kind of fork bomb just an academic issue? No, hackers use it to overload the system and make the system 'useless'.